# getting information from all users of my facebook app

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing some research, where I have a facebook app, that asks for some permissions on the users facebook to get some basic information.

I can see that my app has about 600 users, and I'd like to query them, to see some patterns in the users. i.e. how many friends do they have, how long messages do they post in updates etc.

My question is: **Do I have to copy the data when the user first visits my app and grants access to his information, or can I query it as long as the user hasn't "removed" my app.**

I hope the second option will be true, since I have a lot of considerations about "copying" user data, and storing it in a database - primarily ethical but also related to security issues, compliance, resources so on and so forth.

the programming language is not important, but if anyone needs to exemplify, lets say it's python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO.** You don't have to copy the data.

You can query Facebook as long as you have a valid access token regardless of whether the user is online or offline.

However, the only thing you need to take care of is [handling of expired access token](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/), because in that case the user will need to re-authorize your application for you to get the access_token.